# R rounding off numbers like 8.829847e-07

Tags: r

How can I round off a number like 0.0000234889 (or in the form 8.829847e-07) to a power of ten, either below or above (whichever is my choice), ie here 0.00001 or 0.0001 ?

I tried  round(...., digits=-100000) but it returns an error NaN error.

Ex: `round(2e-07, digits=6)` gives `0`, while I would like `1e-06` and another function to give `1e-07`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Is this what you're looking for?
# find the nearest power of ten for some number
x <- 0.0000234889 # Set test input value
y <- log10(x)     # What is the fractional base ten logarithm?
yy <- round(y)    # What is the nearest whole number base ten log?
xx <- 10 ^ yy     # What integer power of ten is nearest the input?
print(xx)
# [1] 1e-05
```

Comment: In  a single expression it's: 10 ^ round(log10(x))
You can use "ceiling" or "floor" instead of "round" to change functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `digits` argument to the `round()` function must be positive. If you want your number to show up in scientific notation with an exponent `n`, just just do

```
round(value, 10^n)
```

*However*, this will only get you what you want up to a point. For example, you can do `round(0.0000234889, 10^6)` but you still get `2.34889e-05`. (Notice that an exponent of 6 was specified but you got 5.)

Comment: okay, but `round(2e-07, digits=6)` gives 0, while I would like `1e-06` or `1e-07`

Answer (score 0):

Use `options("scipen" = )` like this:

`num <- 0.0000234889`

`> num
[1] 2.34889e-05`

`options("scipen" = 10)`

`options()$scipen`

`> num
[1] 0.0000234889`

This will change the global option for the session. Read documentation here:https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html